# Convert Markdown text to RTF, using Ruby and Pandoc?

Tags: ruby, markdown, rtf, richtext, pandoc

Playing with Ruby and Ruby-Pandoc.  Seems like a nice tool, if I can get it to work.

I'd like to convert some Markdown text (with embedded lists and other fanciness) to Rich Text.  Here's the text I'm converting:

```
Title
===

This is a paragraph. Hallelujah.

Here comes a nested list.
---

* List item 1
  * List item 1.1
  * List item 1.2
* List item 2
  * List item 2.1
```

Here's my Ruby code...

```
require 'pandoc-ruby'

input = File.read(test.md)
converter = PandocRuby.new(input, from: :markdown, to: :rtf)
puts converter.convert
```

... which (after saving the output to a file) produces a document without anything but a title:

[image: screenshot of RTF]

Here's the code of the RTF file:

```
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs36 Title\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 This is a paragraph. Hallelujah.\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs32 Here comes a nested list.\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 1\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 1.1\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 1.2\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 2\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 2.1\sa180\par}
```

In addition, even if it did show up in my RTF viewer (Mac TextEdit), the RTF code seems to have lost all list nesting.  I don't know how to diagnose this, whether I have not stated necessary header information or something in Ruby-Pandoc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your output in a prolog and closing brace.  Like this:

```
{\rtf1\ansi\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Times New Roman;}}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs36 Title\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 This is a paragraph. Hallelujah.\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa180 \li0 \fi0 \b \fs32 Here comes a nested list.\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 1\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 1.1\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 1.2\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 2\par}
{\pard \ql \f0 \sa0 \li360 \fi-360 \bullet \tx360\tab List item 2.1\sa180\par}
}
```

**Update**

*am I missing a "wrapper" configuration setting?*

Yes, as per [the gem readme](https://github.com/alphabetum/pandoc-ruby#pandoc-hint).

> If you are trying to generate a standalone file with full file headers rather than just a marked up fragment, remember to pass the :standalone option so the correct header and footer are added.

*what about the lack of nesting lists?*

As per the [PanDoc documentation](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#the-four-space-rule), your source text is missing 2 more spaces of indentation.

So putting that together, here is the complete solution.

Your source file:

```
Title
===

This is a paragraph. Hallelujah.

Here comes a nested list.
---

* List item 1
    * List item 1.1
    * List item 1.2
* List item 2
    * List item 2.1
```

The conversion code:

```
require 'pandoc-ruby'
input = File.read('./test.md')
puts PandocRuby.markdown(input).to_rtf(:standalone)
```

Comment: OK, I could do that with Ruby string processing, but that would mean hard-coding the fix... is it possible to fix it using Pandoc (i.e., am I missing a "wrapper" configuration setting)?  And what about the lack of nesting lists?

Comment: As for the nested lists, see the [pandoc documentation](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#the-four-space-rule).

Comment: And yes, you're missing a "wrapper" configuration setting: `:standalone`.

Comment: Thanks John, upvoted both comments and incorporated into expanded answer. Also thanks for your work on Pandoc itself, which is badass.